# Getting nth-child to ignore active class with display:none

Tags: html, css

I have a set of links where I need to style the first second and third item of each row separately.

However depending on which page is displayed one of the items will have the class active added to it, which hides that element via `display:none`.

My issue is that the hidden child is still being counted, so the ordering breaks whenever the active class moves to a new position in the arrangement.

I've tried adding `:not(.active)` but this doesn't seem to have any affect.

```css
.flex {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex li {
  width: 33%;
  color: white;
}

.flex li a {
  color: white;
}

.flex li:not(.active):nth-child(3n-1) {
  background-color: red;
}

.flex li:not(.active):nth-child(3n) {
  background-color: blue;
}

.flex li:not(.active):nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: green;
}

.active {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex">
  <li class="active"><a href="/">Link1</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link2</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link3</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link4</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link5</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link6</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link7</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link8</a></li>
  <li class="active"><a href="/">Link9</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link10</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link11</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="/">Link12</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is a different question to:
[Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector)

Reason: Because it's about the active class changing between pages and being dynamic, not about targeting an arbitrary selector

Comment: That's how the `:nth-child` selector works. You can't exclude an item with that selector.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

One solution is to add the color classes directly to the elements.

Comment: If you think that's solution you haven't understood the question or the problem

Comment: the :nth-child selector compares the element index from the DOM to your expression ex: 3n+1. If you add a :not(XY) it will just not render the given styles but the index will increase. because of the `flex`, your content will wrap and the free space from a hidden element will be occupied by the next li element.

Comment: read the duplicate fully not only its *title*. The reason you gave has no sense at all ...

Comment: nth-child doesn't matter, that was my example, if nth child doesn't work, what will? I'm trying to figure out what will allow me to target elements that change their order dynamically but I still need to target first, second and third as they appear on screen?

Comment: no css selector will work... that's what I tried to explain.
if its just the background color and not the links itself, you can add 3 divs with that background behind the links.

Comment: No it's nothing to do with colour that's just the example I used to make it visual