# Select middle elements with different classes from css

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-selectors, selector

I am stuck in an issue where I want to select divs having specific classes within other divs. I want to target middle element with "active" class. In this case the third div with "active" class

I tried using .container .active:nth-child(3) but it is not working. Please help

```css
.container .active:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: red;
}

.container .active:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item active">Active but highlighted</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: you want to select all active classes or only the 3rd active class?

Comment: It's `class`, not `className`.

Comment: Rest of the question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/3558960).

Comment: Your selector will be `.container .active:nth-of-type(3)`

Comment: I want to select the third active class @rtraees

Comment: I am using react that is why it is classNames @RobbyCornelissen

Comment: Then your question should be tagged with `react`.

Comment: Also tried that @ZachJensz it is not working :(

Comment: @AkashRanjan If you want a proper answer please improve your question, create a snippet that can run here, show everything you've tried, you'll probably even figure it out yourself by doing so

Answer (score 0):

The `:nth-of-type()` actually only accounts for the type of element, not the type of class. This is the best solution I can think of right now, I'll update if I figure out a better way:

```css
.container :is(.active + .active + .active):not(.active + .active + .active + .active) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item active">Active but highlighted</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item active">active</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
    <div class="item">abc</div>
  </div>
```