# nth-child doesn't combine with previous selector

Tags: css

I have this HTML and CSS. **I expect the nth-child will select "Test2" and "Test3"** because the previous selector already filters out the "Nothing" element.

If I remove the `:nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3)`, the result selects Test1, Test2, Test3, Test4 (except Nothing). It's correct.

If I remove the `:has(> div[role='article'])`, the result selects "Test1" and "Test2". It's correct.

Why doesn't `nth-child` combine with the previous selector? How can I fix it?

```css
.container[role='feed'] > div:has(> div[role='article']):nth-child(n+2):nth-child(-n+3) {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" role="feed">
  <div>
    <div role="nothing">
        Nothing
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div role="article">
      Test1
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div role="article">
      Test2
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div role="article">
      Test3
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div>
    <div role="article">
      Test4
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Okay, looks like there's no CSS solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector#5546296

Comment: Looks like it. Bleugh