# Combining CSS pseudo classes :has and :nth-of-type

Tags: css, css-selectors

The question of combining pseudo-classes has been covered in different variations before, but this particular case I'm not sure why it's not covered, but I can't get to combine `:has` and `:nth-of-type` in a selector like the following:

```css
div:has(p > span > img):nth-of-type(1)
```

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/1548472, I understand that when doing something like `div.someClass:nth-of-type(2)` it doesn't really care about the `.someClass` specifier, but only focuses on the `div` tag. But from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes#syntax) it kind of indicates that they should be possible to combine as they're both just pseudo classes.

My test environment is within the chromium environment (v. 106), and it doesn't work. Within *Developers Tools* it does reflect that my `.someClass div:has(p > span > img)` has the correct 3 instances, but it's not able to select a specific number within those instances using the `:nth-of-type` selector.

I've found a somewhat hacky workaround for getting to the first of these, by using a combination of `div:has(p > span > img)` for all, and then reverting for the 2nd and onward using `div:has(p > span > img) ~  div:has(p > span > img)`, but it is kind of a hack.

Lastly, it seems like it could be possible to use `:nth-child(2 of <some-selector>)`, so I'm not sure if that also includes a variant like `:nth-child(2 of  div:has(p > span > img))`. Sadly this variant, even if it works, seems not to be included in chromium until v. 111, according to [this](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/g/blink-dev/c/6zLouMDG4Eg).

So the question remains: *Could someone explain why these cant't be combined, or is the `.has(...)` just another variant of the `.someClass` variants which are not supported by the `:nth-of-type` selector, and where does the documentation state that this is the case?*

**Update:** This is *not* the same as the linked question mainly due to two aspects:

- `:has` is a complex selector in most circumstances
- `:has` is a CSS Selector 4 (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has#specifications)

See

Comment: Is this the exact syntax you're using as p > img > span won't work because you can't have a span child in an img?

Comment: It does indeed work with a `img` within a `span`. Oh bummer... The first one is a typo, indeed. Good catch, @Adam

Comment: Hahaha.. that got me confused.  I've had a play about with it and it does appear that :has() is treated like a class selector but I can't find anything in the docs (yet!) that says that's the case.  Mildly frustrating. Urgh

Comment: You already have your answers. nth-child() (or nth-of-type()) doesn't care about "anything"  in the selector whatever the selector is. From the question you linked : "counts elements among all of their siblings under the same parent. It does not count only the siblings that match the rest of the selector." --> note the **rest of the selector**

Comment: Albeit it talks about `:nth-child(... of ???)`, it also says: "Selectors level 4 seeks to rectify this limitation ... ", @TemaniAfif, so there has been some changes (in the recent years), which that answer doesn't respond to.

Comment: read the full sentence : "Selectors level 4 seeks to rectify this limitation by allowing :nth-child(An+B of S) to accept an arbitrary selector argument S". That's your solution and you still need to get this implemented. Nothing has changed since years and :has() has nothing to do with this. The problem is still the same and we are all waiting for the `nth-child( ... of ???)` (Like we were waiting for :has() since 10 years now)