# How to add styles for first and last visible element - Swiper

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components, swiper.js, react-swiper

I am trying to apply styles for first and last elements which  includes class **.swiper-slide-visible**

But I apply styles for all  elements which do not include this class:

```
.swiper-slide-visible:first-child {
mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
}

.swiper-slide-visible:last-child {
 mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%);
}
```

[image: my code]

Styles are applied to 2nd element too.

[image]

**.swiper-wrapper div.swiper-slide-visible:first-child** apply styles to every **div.swiper-slide**

I have a right code for first element

```
.swiper-wrapper > div.swiper-slide-visible

.swiper-wrapper > div.swiper-slide-visible ~ div.swiper-slide-visible
```

**But now I'm working on the last element. Need to find  last element!**

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the current element with tag swiper-slide-visible with a <li>, of course, which is wrapped in a ul, and changing the class of li to swiper-side-visible and removing the class from the current element

Comment: I apply styles for div tag  who  has this class and  this class have been deleted when swiper make a  decision that  this element is not visiable. Can it invoke  a problem?

Comment: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/1427878) - answer: No, and that is the same situation you got here, you are trying to combine a class selector with :first-child/:last-child, which will not work unless the element in question was actually the first/last child of its parent, _regardless of class_.

Comment: You could try an approach similar to the one outlined here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539107/1427878 The first element you are looking for, will be the one that does not have one with the same class before it - so `:not(.swiper-slide-visible) + .swiper-slide-visible`. The same thing doesn't work that easily for the last one though. You'd have to extend the "trickery" quite a bit, to make it work for that one as well.

Comment: I am using  .swiper-slide-visible ~ .swiper-slide-visible but it apply for all  elements too

Comment: Have an  answer for  first but  not last