# How do I detect the last child's tag name to whether add style or not?

Tags: css, sass

I'm using SCSS, and I'm trying to add an `img` tag, if and only if, it's the last child of the parent.

I suppose that I can use `:last-child` to select the last child of it, or `img:last-of-type` to select the last image tag, but how do I detect that the last child is an `img` tag?

```css
#my-div:last-child /* test if this tag's name == img */ {
  padding: 20px;  /* then add a padding to it */
}
```

Comment: You use an id, so it will be unique. If,in your #my-div, there are other items maybe [is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is) can help

Comment: @Sfili_81 Oh my, wait, I think I figured out, that `img:last-child` simply works. If it's not the last child then it doesn't apply the style. For now I don't know why though.

Comment: read this for the why: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/8620333