# Aunt/Uncle selector in CSS?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm currently having this html layout

[image: 1]

How can I select the imgs in the "MenuDisplayFocus" div accordingly to input[type="radio"] so that for example when I check the first input, I can select only the first image?

I tried to look up such problem on the internet but most will have the imgs be an input's child or directly adjacent to it, is there no such way to choose like what I described?

Comment: Generally, CSS can only go up the document tree, not back down towards the root.

Comment: please share a code snippet

Comment: Please post a minimal structure of your HTML as text, not as an image.

Comment: _"but most will have the imgs be an input's child"_ - _that_ would be impossible to begin with; input fields do not have _children_.

Comment: Does the HTML _have_ to be this structure, or can you modify it? If you were able to move the radio buttons themselves into #MenuDisplayFocus or before it, then this could be done without `:has()` and its still rather limited browser support. The input fields themselves would get visually hidden, and divs would become what they should have been in the first place - proper `label` elements. If an indicator for which option was currently chosen was needed on the labels themselves as well, that could be implemented using pseudo elements, also based on the checkboxes' `:checked` state

Comment: Sorry, this is my 2nd post so I didn't know I should've posted a code snippet instead. Forgive me for posting my question incorrectly, I actually meant sibling's child, not an input's child. ThankCBroe for pointing out I should use label instead of div, and yes I'd prefer to have that layout since I intended to have those imgs laid on top of those inputs, and I don't think I can use z-index since I'm putting those into a grid with them having static position, I'm too new to find another way but if you can understand and have a more professional way to do that, I'll very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, you can do this but you need the `:has()` pseudo class and there's a gotcha.

We can use :has() to select the parent so in this case we're looking at the #menu div and testing the first input box. Because the first input box is actually the 2nd child of the #menu div (the first child is the div with id of MenuFocus) we have to use nth-child(2) to select the first input box.  We can't combine the nth-child selector with other rules to 'filter' unwanted items (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/12571484) answer on stackoverflow for details),

If this is checked then we can then select the first image using the descendant combinator.

Note that :has() isn't currently supported across all browsers. You can check this on [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas)

A good primer on :has() can be found [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-has-selector/) and here's a good [video](https://youtu.be/OGJvhpoE8b4) by Kevin Powell on this.

**Edite to add**
`nth-of-type` will also work and it makes things a bit more logical. Code added below

P.S. it's much easier for other contributors if you post the actual code rather than a screen shot. It helps you get your answers faster and avoids your question getting closed.

```css
#menu:has(input[type="checkbox"]:nth-child(2):checked) #MenuDisplayFocus img:first-child {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  <div id='MenuInfo'>
    <div id='MenuDisplayFocus'>
      <img src='https://placekitten.com/200/200'>
      <img src='https://placekitten.com/g/200/200'>
    </div>
    <input type='checkbox' id='SoccerFields' checked='checked'>
    <div id='SoccerfieldsDescription' class='Description'>XXX</div>
    <input type='checkbox' id='Employees'>
    <div id='EmployeesDescription' class='Description'>YYY</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nth-of-type example

```css
#menu:has(input[type="checkbox"]:first-of-type:checked) #MenuDisplayFocus img:first-child {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}

#menu:has(input[type="checkbox"]:nth-of-type(2):checked) #MenuDisplayFocus img:nth-child(2) {
  outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='menu'>
  <div id='MenuInfo'>
    <div id='MenuDisplayFocus'>
      <img src='https://placekitten.com/200/200'>
      <img src='https://placekitten.com/g/200/200'>
    </div>
    <input type='checkbox' id='SoccerFields' checked='checked'>
    <div id='SoccerfieldsDescription' class='Description'>XXX</div>
    <input type='checkbox' id='Employees'>
    <div id='EmployeesDescription' class='Description'>YYY</div>
  </div>
</div>
```