# <div> vs <nav> when selecting last-of-type by .class in a nested structure

Tags: html, css

I want to keep it simple. The idea is to select the last immediate child by a certain class in a nested structure. Why it works with `<nav>` tag but `<div>`?

### With `<div>` tag:

```css
.super > .sub:last-of-type {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<div class="super">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <div class="super">
    <div class="sub">_1</div>
    <div class="sub">_2</div>
    <div class="super">
      <div class="sub">__1</div>
      <div class="sub">__2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### With `<nav>` tag:

```css
.super > .sub:last-of-type {
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<nav class="super">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div>
  <nav class="super">
    <div class="sub">_1</div>
    <div class="sub">_2</div>
    <nav class="super">
      <div class="sub">__1</div>
      <div class="sub">__2</div>
    </nav>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

So I have two questions here.

1. Why?
2. Could I even achieve the same `<nav>` behaviour with `<div>` tag?

Comment: [This is worth a read](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5546296/12571484)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the confusion you are having is that `:last-of-type` can be thought of as "last of tag" rather than "last of selector".

So, when you do `.sub:last-of-type` and you are using all DIVs, you are effectively saying "the last div which also has the class `.sub`". Let's look at your code again:

```html
<div class="super">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div> <!-- this is not the last DIV -->
  <div class="super">
    <div class="sub">_1</div>
    <div class="sub">_2</div> <!-- this is not the last DIV -->
    <div class="super">
      <div class="sub">__1</div>
      <div class="sub">__2</div> <!-- this IS the last DIV -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In the above example, you have two DIVs which are not the last of type DIV, even thought they are the last of type with class `.sub` - that's not what the `:last-of-type` selector targets. It's confusing.

When you use nav, the `.sub` elements are indeed the last of type "DIV":

```
<nav class="super">
  <div class="sub">1</div>
  <div class="sub">2</div> <!-- this is the last of type DIV -->
  <nav class="super">
    <div class="sub">_1</div>
    <div class="sub">_2</div> <!-- this is the last of type DIV -->
    <nav class="super">
      <div class="sub">__1</div>
      <div class="sub">__2</div> <!-- this is the last of type DIV -->
    </nav>
  </nav>
</nav>
```

**UPDATE (from comments):** My suggestion would be to use any tag other than DIV for the `.super` elements as is done with the `nav` tags above. You can even create your own [custom elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_custom_elements).

The OP eventually found a CSS-only solution which I am posting on their behest, though I personally find it hard to read and understand. It is a clever solution nonetheless:

```css
.super > .sub:has(+ .super), 
.super > .sub:last-child { 
  background-color: turquoise; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand but this abstraction does not feel reasonable. I should be applying the attached psudo selector (`:last-of-type` or even `:last-child`) to an already filtered set of `.sub` class immediate children elements. Even `div:nth-last-child(1 of .sub)` doesnt work because it seems to first find the last child and then check if it is `.sub` class. Can you show me a way around this problem without JS and i accept your answer.

Comment: Unfortunately psuedo selectors do not further filter a set the way you want. Cascading selectors do, but not pseudo selectors. I think the solution is already laid out for you: you can't do what you want using all DIVs - so pick any other tag for the `.super` items. You can even create your own custom elements if you want... just don't use all DIVs. There is no CSS-only way out using all DIVs. Oh, and whiskey... whiskey is essential to learning all of the quirks of CSS and getting good at it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.... I had my Laphroaig and... `.super > .sub:has(+ .super), .super > .sub:last-child { background-color: turquoise; }` did the job. :) Perhaps you would like to ammend your answer to show it for the integrity of this "closed" question.