# Add glow to 1 of 6 images depending on link hovered

Tags: html, css, hover

I've tried numerous ways to do this without success. I have 6 "icons" and I will have 20-30 links. I want to add an outer glow to one of the icons, depending on which link is hovered. I'm using Bootstrap 5 in this sample code. Here I'm trying to add the effect to the second image when the link 5.html is hovered.

```css
.division-icon {
  background-color: #ff8066;
  border: solid 4px #c34a36;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  position: relative;
}

.division-icon img {
  width: 50px;
}

a[href="5.html"]:hover+div .division-icon:nth-child(2) img {
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 3px #d06e5e;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="environmental-health.html" title=""><img src="images/restaurant.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="wellness-health-promotion.html" title=""><img src="images/wellness.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="maternal-child-health.html" title=""><img src="images/mch.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="adult-services.html" title=""><img src="images/tas.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="dental-health.html" title=""><img src="images/dental.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="administration.html" title=""><img src="images/admin.svg" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="1.html">1</a>
<a href="2.html">2</a>
<a href="3.html">3</a>
<a href="4.html">4</a>
<a href="5.html">5</a>
<a href="this-is-the-url.html">this is the url</a>
<a href="test-url.html">test url</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) won't work because the element you're hovering over isn't a direct sibling of the element you're trying to apply the box shadow to. You have two options. Either you put the `a` elements before the div containing the images then use a combination of the [general sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator), the descendent selector and attribute selectors to target the element.

The neater (but more unsupported way) is to use the [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo class but this isn't supported across all browsers (see [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/?search=%3Ahas) for details). In addition the nth-child() psuedo class doesn't work as you'd think it would with class selectors so use with care. I've avoided this by adding an attribute to your html and selecting the element on that. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/12571484) for details)

```css
.division-icon {
  background-color: #ff8066;
  border: solid 4px #c34a36;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  position: relative;
}

.division-icon img {
  width: 50px;
}

body:has(a[href="5.html"]:hover) img[data-target="5"] {
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="environmental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="wellness-health-promotion.html" title=""><img data-target='5' src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="maternal-child-health.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="adult-services.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="dental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="administration.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="1.html">1</a>
<a href="2.html">2</a>
<a href="3.html">3</a>
<a href="4.html">4</a>
<a href="5.html">5</a>
<a href="this-is-the-url.html">this is the url</a>
<a href="test-url.html">test url</a>
```

**Edit** if the links go above the buttons as suggested in your comment you can use the general sibling combinator

```css
.division-icon {
  background-color: #ff8066;
  border: solid 4px #c34a36;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  position: relative;
}

.division-icon img {
  width: 50px;
}

a[href="5.html"]:hover ~ * [data-target="5"] {
  transition: box-shadow 0.1s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<a href="1.html">1</a>
<a href="2.html">2</a>
<a href="3.html">3</a>
<a href="4.html">4</a>
<a href="5.html">5</a>
<a href="this-is-the-url.html">this is the url</a>
<a href="test-url.html">test url</a>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="environmental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target='5'>
      <a href="wellness-health-promotion.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="maternal-child-health.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="adult-services.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="dental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="administration.html" title=""><img src="https://placekitten.com/50/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Finally if you wanted to do this in javascript, I've added a bit that looks for all elements with the `data-hover` attribute. On the mouseenter event it then looks for the corresponding element with the `data-target` attribute. It should be fairly self-explanatory. This will work irrespective of where any of the elements are in the html.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hover]');
  elements.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('mouseenter', event => {
      getTargetElement(event.target).classList.add('data-target-hover');
    });
    element.addEventListener('mouseleave', event => {
      getTargetElement(event.target).classList.remove('data-target-hover');
    });
  });
}

function getTargetElement(element) {
  const target = element.getAttribute('data-hover');
  return document.querySelector(`[data-target="${target}"]`);
}
```

```css
.division-icon {
  background-color: #ff8066;
  border: solid 4px #c34a36;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  position: relative;
}

.division-icon img {
  width: 50px;
}

.data-target-hover {
  transition: 0.1s linear;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 5px blue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image1">
      <a href="environmental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image2">
      <a href="wellness-health-promotion.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/238/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="maternal-child-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/239/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" data-target="image4">
      <a href="adult-services.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/231/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="dental-health.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/232/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-1">
    <div class="division-icon d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      <a href="administration.html" title=""><img src="https://picsum.photos/id/233/50" /></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3">
  </div>
</div>

<a href="1.html">1</a>
<a href="2.html">2</a>
<a href="3.html">3</a>
<a href="4.html" data-hover="image4">4</a>
<a href="5.html" data-hover="image2">5</a>
```

Comment: I made an error in my description of what I wanted. What I want is the glow on the circle div, not the image it's self.

Comment: I've tried using an id tag and this, but it doesn't work.  a[href="2.html"]:hover + #two {

Comment: the links will probably go above the buttons.

Comment: I'll have a look tomorrow if that's OK 

Comment: That would be great. Thank you. 

I’m ok with just css, JavaScript, query. Whatever gets it done.

Comment: I've edited the answer with a css and a javascript example

Comment: Thanks Adam!!! That really helps a lot, thanks for taking time to help. I'm using the javascript, I think it will work better for what I'm working on. Works perfectly.

Comment: Adam, if you see this I have one more question. This javascript is a little beyond what I know. I know it should be easy to do this. How would I change the javascript to append the data-hover to the end of the data-target-hover class, like data-target-hover-image1? The idea to apply a different color hover effect to the corresponding icon instead of one color for all.