# CSS - Get amount of element with selector

Tags: html, css

This a long shot, but here goes..

```
.cell:nth-child(3n) {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

This currently applies the `border-right` property to every third element that has the `.cell` class.

What I want to do is make it more dynamic by having it check how many `.cell` elements there are, then performing some calculation on that number, and then using *that* resulting value be the combined with `n`.

E.g:

```
.cell:nth-child(
  (((number of .cell elements) * 2)n)
) {
  border-right: 2px solid black;
}
```

Does that make sense? Basically, instead of just being `3n`, it now gets the amount of elements with `.cell` as a call, multiplies *that* with 2 and then "concatenates" the result to n.

Does CSS have anything like that? Or anything that could achieve the same result?

Comment: I don't believe so; there have been calls to allow [CSS counters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter) to be used inside of [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) ([example request](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/1026)) to facilitate this though nothing has (yet) come of that due to the various problems (the severity of the "problems" is very much a subjective assessment). I think - currently - that JavaScript is the only means to do this client-side, though back end options are certainly also possible.

Comment: _"This currently applies the border-right property to every third element that has the .cell class."_ - no, it _doesn't_ actually do that - see [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/1427878)

Comment: _"Does CSS have anything like that?"_ - no. _"Or anything that could achieve the same result?"_ - you could write what's been dubbed "quantity queries" to select elements only when they occur in certain numbers - but you would still have to explicitly write all the possible situations explicitly in your CSS, there is no logic to do the kind of "calculation" you want.

Comment: what you want is not logical. If you have 5 cells then your selector will be (10n) which mean you will target 0, 10, 20 ... but you only have 5 cells