# CSS Selector to find a subset of entities based on a class filter

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have I have a table with a series of rows represented, in that set of tables there are some rows that have a class of "clickable". What I am attempting to do, is to apply style to every odd row that has the class of "clickable". I have attempted various selectors, but it only seems to apply the style to the odd rows of clickable that are odd when applied to all the table rows, not just those with the "clickable" class. I guess I need the selector to find the subset of rows with the class "clickable", and then iterate those for the odd children.

If rows 1,4,5,7 and 8 are clickable, then I want rows 4 & 7 to be considered the odd rows here. However, it seems to look at 1(c),2,3,4(c),5(c),6,7(c),8(c),9,10 and when looking for odd rows with clickable (used a c for reference) only 4, 8 are chosen since they sit in the odd positions of the entire set of the rows.

I have tried numerous selectors, without luck. I'm hoping that this is a possible scenario, and someone can help me with some feedback or if possible a solution.

```css
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  width: 100px;
}

.clickable {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.clickable:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Dean</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Gina</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Alex</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Eli</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Emma</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Sophie</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Sarah</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all code necessary to reproduce the issue *in the question itself*, not just on CodePen. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992) for a similar experience.

Comment: Thanks LS_, I appreciate the link. It mostly confirms my suspicion that the selectors do not allow for what I am looking for directly, with the exception of the level 4 selector that has not yet received broad support.

Comment: I'll update for completeness Heretic, thought the codepen would be more convenient but can understand why seeing it all in a single post is easier for more feedback. Also, thanks for pointing out Stack Snippets, definitely will use that as well going forward.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```css
tr:nth-child(even of .clickable) {
    background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

The source of the answer is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/16638995)

Or use java script / jquery for broad browser support:

```js
$('tr.clickable').each(function(index, value) {
  if(index % 2 != 0)
  $(value).addClass('custom-bg');
});
```

```css
td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
  width: 100px;
}

.clickable {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.clickable.custom-bg {
  background-color: lightcoral;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Dean</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Fred</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>False</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Gina</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>False</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Sam</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Alex</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>False</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Eli</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Emma</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td>Sophie</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>False</Td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row clickable">
    <td>Sarah</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>True</Td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: For readers: Note that this feature [is new](https://caniuse.com/css-nth-child-of) and hence not very well supported.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include references and information as to how and why the code presented helps solve the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks Nissim, I did see this in the specifications as well but my solution requires broad browser support unfortunately.

Comment: I edited the answer with an option to do it with Jquery, I hope it's good for you.