# How can I get Smalĺcaps using first line in mid-chapter within a class in css?

Tags: css, paragraph, smallcaps

I know this within css will give me the first line, in the first paragragh only:

```
  p:first-of-type::first-line {
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-variant-alternates: normal;
  font-variant-position: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  font-variant-ligatures: none;
  }
```

However, I'm trying to do this mid-chapter, after three asterisks * * * and the new paragraph after this calls for small caps. The paragraph after the asterisks has a class named newpara. How can I use the above and maybe use the newpara class? And I would like to use this again after the asterisks. And I know I could use spans but this could get tedious.

I did try:

```
  .newpara:first-of-type::first-line {
  font-variant-numeric: normal;
  font-variant: small-caps;
  font-variant-alternates: normal;
  font-variant-position: normal;
  font-variant-east-asian: normal;
  letter-spacing: 0.04em;
  font-variant-ligatures: none;
  }
```

That didn't work.

Any help is welcomed.

Thank you!

Comment: You can not combine `:first-of-type` with a class selector like that, this is the same issue as explained in [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649/1427878)

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of your issue, when asking a question like this - including a proper example of the HTML. Mere verbal descriptions are often too vague, ambiguous, or leave out relevant detail.

Comment: <p class="para">This is mid chapter and not at the start. I'm just using this as an example</p>

  <p class="asterisks">*  *  *</p>

  <p class="newpara">I want this new paragraph to have small caps for the first line only, mid-chapter and trying not to use spans.</p>

I've read a little of nth child but I have very little understanding of it. If I have to use nth child, how would it be set in CSS and html?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can target the first `.newpara` element that directly follows an `.asterisks` element, by using the [adjacent sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator), `+`:

```css
p { max-width: 20em; }

.asterisks + .newpara::first-line {
  font-variant: small-caps;
}
```

```html
<p class="para">This is mid chapter and not at the start. I'm just using this as an example</p>
<p class="asterisks">* * *</p>
<p class="newpara">I want this new paragraph to have small caps for the first line only, mid-chapter and trying not to use spans.</p>
<p class="newpara">Lorem ipsum.</p>
```