# How to use :first-of-type together with :has

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have this HTML and I want to set the display of the first section with a child element only to none

```css
.entry-content section:has(img):first-of-type {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
  <div>
    <section></section>
    <section>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section></section>
    <section>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div><img src="" alt=""></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
    <section></section>
    <section>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div><img src="" alt="">test</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't know why this isn't working.

```css
.entry-content section:has(img):first-of-type{
display:none}
```

I want it to affect only the first section that has an image child within

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5545649). In your case, the solution would be `.entry-content :nth-child(1 of section:has(img))`.

Comment: Because the first `section` doesn't have an `img`. `:first-of-type` doesn't take other selectors into account; it only takes the "type" (i.e. tag name) into account.