# CSS selector that only selects the first cell of each row with specific class name

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to write CSS selector that given this table

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 2</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target">Cell 5</td>
    <td>Cell 6</td>
    <td>Cell 7</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Selects only "Cell 2" and "Cell 5"? The order in which a cell might have the class name is random for each row. The only guarantee is each row must have at least one cell with the class.

I've tried something like `td.target:first-of-type`, but selectors like this apply the pseduo class first and then restrict the class name, resulting "Cell 5". I need to apply the class name first while maintaining its n-th child state, then apply the `:first-of-type`.

Is this possible?

Comment: Will you always be targeting the *first* `.target` element in a row?

Comment: Your question has me scratching my head. May I know for clarification as to what your specific goal is in this table?

Comment: Try to scrape a website. Their table sometimes has 6 columns, sometimes 7. The one I need either sits at the 3rd or 4th, but always the first with the class name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target all the `.target` elements, that are not a `.target` following a `.target` :-)

```css
.target:not(.target ~ .target) { color: red }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 2</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target">Cell 5</td>
    <td>Cell 6</td>
    <td>Cell 7</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `nth-child()`

```css
td:nth-child(1 of .target) { color: red }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell 1</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 2</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 3</td>
    <td>Cell 4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="target">Cell 5</td>
    <td>Cell 6</td>
    <td>Cell 7</td>
    <td class="target">Cell 8</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's nice, didn't know what was possible now. I see someone mentioned it in the "classic" [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75827187/1427878) a while back as well, which is good to keep in mind for further reference.

Comment: Also correct answer. In fact I think this answer is more flexible than CBroe's, because you can specifically target the nth, while the other can only target first and last. But alas, he was faster to the line. Take my upvote though.