# CSS: how to conditionally select the last X nth-last-of-type only when any of them has a class?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Using CSS only, I would like to select the last 4 elements, but only when any of them has the "selected" class.

*In the snippet you can see in the second row how i'd like it to work.*

```js
let sel=0;
setTimeout(setSelected, 1000);

function setSelected() {
  document.getElementById("d"+sel).classList.remove("selected");
  document.getElementById("j"+sel).classList.remove("selected");

  if (++sel>5) sel = 0;
  document.getElementById("d"+sel).classList.add("selected");

  // This is only to show what i would like to get with CSS selectors
  document.getElementById("j"+sel).classList.add("selected");
  if (sel>=3) {
    document.getElementById("j3").classList.add("active");
    document.getElementById("j4").classList.add("active");
    document.getElementById("j5").classList.add("active");
  }else{
    document.getElementById("j3").classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("j4").classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("j5").classList.remove("active");
  }
  setTimeout(setSelected, 1000);
}
```

```css
.container {text-align: center;}
.normal, .example {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: #004;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.normal:last-of-type,
.normal:nth-last-of-type(2),
.normal:nth-last-of-type(3)
{
  background-color: #A00;
}
.selected{
  background-color: #0A0;
  border: 2px solid #0A0;
}
.active{background-color: #A00;}
```

```html
<p>CSS Only</p>
<div class="container">
  <div id="d0" class="normal selected">0</div>
  <div id="d1" class="normal">1</div>
  <div id="d2" class="normal">2</div>
  <div id="d3" class="normal">3</div>
  <div id="d4" class="normal">4</div>
  <div id="d5" class="normal">5</div>
</div>
<p>example with Javascript</p>
<div class="container">
  <div id="j0" class="example selected">0</div>
  <div id="j1" class="example">1</div>
  <div id="j2" class="example">2</div>
  <div id="j3" class="example">3</div>
  <div id="j4" class="example">4</div>
  <div id="j5" class="example">5</div>
</div>
```

I started by selection the last of them:

```
.normal:last-of-type,
.normal:nth-last-of-type(2),
.normal:nth-last-of-type(3)
{
  background-color: #A00;
}
```

but then i wasn't able to go further; by reading the description of CSS [:has()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) i have the impression that a clever combination of it and `nth-last-of-type()` could get me there, but i can't figure out how should that "stack" of selectors be built.

Is it possible, using only CSS, to conditionally select the last 3 items only if one of them has the "selected" class?
If yes, how?

-EDIT-
Since the question was close 'cause seems to be a duplicate of [Can I combine :nth-child() or :nth-of-type() with an arbitrary selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector) :

My problem is that i need to select **ALL** of the last three divs when only one of them match an arbitrary selector, while in the linked question all of the selected elements matches the selector.

Trying to say it in another way, i need to select the elements 3, 4 and 5 when either 3 or 4 or 5 has the "selected" class.

Comment: there are many issues here.  The first issue relevant issue is, that `.normal` is a class, not a type.  `nth-type` selects elements by its tag such as `div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `.container:has(.selected:nth-last-of-type(-n + 3)) > :nth-last-of-type(-n + 3)`. When the container has an element with `.selected` and that element is one of the last 3, select the last 3

```js
let sel=0;
setTimeout(setSelected, 1000);

function setSelected() {
  document.getElementById("d"+sel).classList.remove("selected");
  document.getElementById("j"+sel).classList.remove("selected");

  if (++sel>5) sel = 0;
  document.getElementById("d"+sel).classList.add("selected");

  // This is only to show what i would like to get with CSS selectors
  document.getElementById("j"+sel).classList.add("selected");
  if (sel>=3) {
    document.getElementById("j3").classList.add("active");
    document.getElementById("j4").classList.add("active");
    document.getElementById("j5").classList.add("active");
  }else{
    document.getElementById("j3").classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("j4").classList.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("j5").classList.remove("active");
  }
  setTimeout(setSelected, 1000);
}
```

```css
.container {text-align: center;}
.normal, .example {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: #004;
  text-align: center;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}

.container:has(.selected:nth-last-of-type(-n + 3)) > :nth-last-of-type(-n + 3) {
  background-color: #A00;
}
.selected{
  background-color: #0A0;
  border: 2px solid #0A0;
}
.active{background-color: #A00;}
```

```html
<p>CSS Only</p>
<div class="container">
  <div id="d0" class="normal selected">0</div>
  <div id="d1" class="normal">1</div>
  <div id="d2" class="normal">2</div>
  <div id="d3" class="normal">3</div>
  <div id="d4" class="normal">4</div>
  <div id="d5" class="normal">5</div>
</div>
<p>example with Javascript</p>
<div class="container">
  <div id="j0" class="example selected">0</div>
  <div id="j1" class="example">1</div>
  <div id="j2" class="example">2</div>
  <div id="j3" class="example">3</div>
  <div id="j4" class="example">4</div>
  <div id="j5" class="example">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! Better than my answer. Have an upvote!

Comment: excellent but there's a problem here that some of browsers doesn't support `:has` pseudo by default, so it will not make sense at this case for some users

Comment: Thanks a lot, this work wonderfully, and it just need to change the "3" to make it work with whatever number of element i want to be highlighted.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with a combination of `nth-last-of-type()` and `:has`.

```js
/* For demo. Set .selected on click */
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".container > div");
items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', onclick);
});

function onclick(){
    document.querySelector(".selected").classList.remove("selected")
   this.classList.add("selected");
}
```

```css
.selected {
  outline:2px dotted;
}
/* Test if relational pseudo-classes are supported. At the time of writing Firefox is lagging behind. */
@supports selector(:has(*)) {
  /* 
  If the last nth is selected
  or HAS a subsequent sibling which is selected
  then highlight it and the siblings: 
  */
  .container div:nth-last-of-type(3):is(.selected),
  .container div:nth-last-of-type(3):has(~.selected),
  .container div:nth-last-of-type(3):is(.selected) ~ div,
  .container div:nth-last-of-type(3):has(~.selected) ~ div {
    background: green;
  }
}
```

```html
click an item:
<div class="container">
  <div id="d0" class="normal selected">0</div>
  <div id="d1" class="normal">1</div>
  <div id="d2" class="normal">2</div>
  <div id="d3" class="normal">3</div>
  <div id="d4" class="normal">4</div>
  <div id="d5" class="normal">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! While i've accepted the other anwer as it is more pratical, would you like to teach me what each line exactly do?