# How to hide second row of a table using css?

Tags: html, css

I have one table

```
<table>
<tr><td>test data 1</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

To hide second row of table i am using following css

```
 table tr:nth-child(2) {display : none;}
```

But not working in all browser.
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751127/how-can-i-select-first-second-or-third-element-with-given-class-name-using-css

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:nth-child()` simply [doesn't work in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-child) (mainly IE), if you wish to hide the second row using CSS2, you could add a specific class:

```
<table>
<tr><td>test data 1</td></tr>
<tr class="row2"><td>test data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 5</td></tr>
</table>

 table tr.row2 {display : none;}
```

Comment: As of Sep 2018, the link in this answer shows a largely-red chart as the upper half of the search results. You might instead want to look into [this link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3) instead.

Answer (score 7):

Use the adjacency selector :

```
table tr:FIRST-CHILD + tr
{
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: +1 For CSS 2.1 solution (IE 7+, cf. [When Can I Use...](http://caniuse.com/#search=first-))

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to give it a class name.

```
<table>
<tr><td>test data 1</td></tr>
<tr class="hide_me"><td>test data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 5</td></tr>
</table>
```

and then

```
.hide_me { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/p2b8H/1/

Use Jquery eq(1) means, 0=> first row, 1 =>second row, 2=> third row ...etc

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('table tr:eq(1)').remove();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, selectors like `:nth-child()` aren't supported by old browsers.

But you can always use a class, e.g. `.invisible {display:none}` and apply it to the `<tr>` you want to hide.

```
<table>
<tr><td>test data 1</td></tr>
<tr class="invisible"><td>test data 2</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 3</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 4</td></tr>
<tr><td>test data 5</td></tr>
</table>
```