# CSS select first element regardless its levels

Tags: html, css, selector

I can not assure the level of my condition, but it should be the first incidence. I am almost sure there is no way, but only for assertion:

Here is some HTML sample:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="title"></div>
</div>
```

So my selector might be `#container .title`, but let us imagine `.title` may appear at more than one level inside `#container` and it need to be labeled as it is, then more strictly I do `#container > .title`. Despite not always it will be the only one happening in that level, so I do `#container > .title:first-child`.

Ok, although not always it will be the first level, so I regress to ensure that by doing `#container .title:first-child`, but it breaks with several levels:

```
<div id="container">
  <foo>
    <div class="title"></div>
  </foo>
  <bar>
    <div class="title"></div>
  </bar>
</div>
```

Both will be selected, I want only the first incidence. Is there any way to do that with CSS selectors?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not doable, that's the conclusion from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751127/how-can-i-select-first-second-or-third-element-with-given-class-name-using-css

Comment: This is the closest you can probably get with css, but it will fail in certain cases (like the one in the fiddle) http://jsfiddle.net/gwa42/. There's no way to go back up in the document tree if the first title is inside a div and there are others outside that div but inside another div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `universal selector`.

```
#container > *:first-child > .title:first-child { color:red; }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/H5hHj/

**Edited:** See if is that what you need: http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/H5hHj/3/

**Edited 2:** I don't know if it is allowed in your case, but take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/felipemiosso/H5hHj/9/

**Edited 3:** After a few tries ... the final answer is: NOT POSSIBLE =|

Comment: But it can happen in a unknown number of levels, bay be `#container > .here` or `#container > * > .here` or `#container > * > * > .here` and so on...

Comment: Oh... I see, now. The name of the class could change, too?

Comment: No, but may happen other styles for the same class in other cases, that is why the name can not change and it need to be applied for the first incidence.

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding: as I read it, the OP wants to find the first instance of `.title` — regardless of nesting or whether it is the `:first-child`…

Comment: Almost it, @brouxhaha found a gap.

Comment: @Barney I want a selector like jQuery(":first"), it is not the first child (of its parent), it is the first element from all context inside the #content regardless the complexity of levels

Comment: @Tiago I know; and I'm afraid it isn't possible :( — even [CSS4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) doesn't provide an API for this.

Comment: I don't think you can count on there being a `.title` in the first set of divs - if there aren't any, this breaks again: http://jsfiddle.net/H5hHj/10/.

Comment: Thanks for the effort, folks! Should I mark this answer as right or leave it?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is use Jquery or javascript

```
$(".title:first").css( "color", "red" );
```

Comment: Yeah, but let us hope some more time, maybe there is another answer.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer. If you add a javascript solution then it would be an answer, but as it is this does not answer the question at all