# What is the difference between :first-child and :first-of-type?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I can't tell the difference between `element:first-child` and `element:first-of-type`

For example say, you had a div

`div:first-child`
→ All `<div>` elements that are the first child of their parent.

`div:first-of-type`
→ All `<div>` elements that are the first `<div>` element of their parent.

This seems like the exact same thing, but they work differently.

Could someone please explain?

Comment: First child only targets the first child of the parent, where the first of type targets the first child of that type (div or a span or whatever it is you are trying to target)

Comment: The first 'div' child might have an older sibling.  first-of-type selects such a div since it is the first child of the type, first-child would not select that div because it's not the first child element.

Answer (score 281, accepted):

A parent element can have one or more child elements:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

Among these children, only one of them can be the first. This is matched by `:first-child`:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>Child</div> <!-- :first-child -->
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

The difference between `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` is that `:first-of-type` will match the first element of its element type, which in HTML is represented by its tag name, *even if that element is not the first child of the parent*. So far the child elements we're looking at have all been `div`s, but bear with me, I'll get to that in a bit.

For now, the converse also holds true: any `:first-child` is also `:first-of-type` by necessity. Since the first child here is also the first `div`, it will match *both* pseudo-classes, as well as the type selector `div`:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>Child</div> <!-- div:first-child, div:first-of-type -->
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

Now, if you change the type of the first child from `div` to something else, like `h1`, it will still be the first child, but it will no longer be the first `div` obviously; instead, it becomes the first (and only) `h1`. If there are any other `div` elements following this first child within the same parent, the first of those `div` elements will then match `div:first-of-type`. In the given example, the second child becomes the first `div` after the first child is changed to an `h1`:

```
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Child</h1>   <!-- h1:first-child, h1:first-of-type -->
  <div>Child</div> <!-- div:nth-child(2), div:first-of-type -->
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

Note that `:first-child` is equivalent to `:nth-child(1)`.

This also implies that while any element may only have a single child element matching `:first-child` at a time, it can and will have as many children matching the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class as the number of types of children it has. In our example, the selector `.parent > :first-of-type` (with an implicit `*` qualifying the `:first-of-type` pseudo) will match *two* elements, not just one:

```
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Child</h1>   <!-- .parent > :first-of-type -->
  <div>Child</div> <!-- .parent > :first-of-type -->
  <div>Child</div>
  <div>Child</div>
</div>
```

The same holds true for `:last-child` and `:last-of-type`: any `:last-child` is by necessity also `:last-of-type`, since absolutely no other element follows it within its parent. Yet, because the last `div` is also the last child, the `h1` cannot be the last child, despite being the last of its type.

`:nth-child()` and `:nth-of-type()` function very similarly in principle when used with an arbitrary integer argument (as in the `:nth-child(1)` example mentioned above), but where they differ is in the potential number of elements matched by `:nth-of-type()`. This is covered in detail in [What is the difference between p:nth-child(2) and p:nth-of-type(2)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493178/what-is-the-difference-between-pnth-child2-and-pnth-of-type2)

Comment: I finally understand. If I wanted the first div under a div element I would call div:first-of-type, because there could be non-div elements above it. It was a little confusing, but I understand now. This is an excellent and very informative post. Thank you and your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've created a sample based on this answer: https://codepen.io/bigtinabang/pen/pmMPxO

Answer (score 19):

I have created an example to demonstrate the difference between `first-child` and `first-of-type` here.

```css
    .parent :first-child {
      color: red;
    }

    .parent :first-of-type {
      background: yellow;
    }

    .parent p:first-child {
      text-decoration: line-through;
    }

    /* Does not work */
    .parent div:first-child {
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    /* Use this instead */
    .parent div:first-of-type {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    /* This is second child regardless of its type */
    .parent div:nth-child(2) {
      border: 1px black solid;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
      <p>Child</p>
      <div>Child</div>
      <div>Child</div>
      <div>Child</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's quickly understood and complete, in combination with the Fiddle.

Comment: why is there no text-decoration: underline, or border????

Comment: True - The "use this instead" example doesnt have any style applied to it

Answer (score 0):

The difference  between the first-child-type and first-child can be understand with  the example.you need to understand the follwing example created by me and it really work you can paste the codes in your editor you will understand what they are and how they work

Code #1 for first-of-type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>clear everything</title>
<style>
p:first-of-type{
color:red;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>
<p class="p1">some text</p>
<div>
<p class="p2">some text</p>
<div>
<p class="p3">some text</p>
</div>
<p class="p4">some text</p>
</div>
<p class="p5">some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

result

.p1,.p2,.p3 will be styled  and thier color will be red.even if we put .p1 after 
the second div it will be red.

Code #2 for  first-child:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>clear everything</title>
<style>
p:first-child{
color:red;
}
</style>
<head>
<body>
<p class="p1">some text</p>
<div>
<p class="p2">some text</p>
<div>
<p class="p3">some text</p>
</div>
<p class="p4">some text</p>
</div>
<p class="p5">some text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

result:

if we put the .p2 after the second div 2 it  will not be red however in the first 
case it was working.

Comment: Redundant answer that is of lesser quality than the one by the community wiki.

Answer (score 0):

The `:first-child` pseudo-class selects an element that is the first element among a group of sibling elements **if it is the first child of its parent**. On the other hand, `:first-of-type` selects the first element of the specified type among a group of sibling elements **regardless of whether it's the first child of its parent**.