# CSS first-child doesn't work for the second time

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML:

```
  <div class="row">
         <div id="sidebar" class="column large-2 medium-3">
             <div class="row">
               test
             </div>
         </div>
         <div id="rightside" class="column large-10 medium-9">
             <div class="row">test2</div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#rightside:first-child{
 border-bottom:solid 1px @main_color;
text-align:center;

}
#sidebar:first-child{
   border-bottom:solid 1px @main_color;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I'm using Zurb Foundation 5.  The sidebar first-child works, but the one for the #rightside elements does not. Any idea why?

I've inspected the element #rightside and I can't see the CSS selector that I've applied in the inspector in Chrome. It seems that it doesn't recognize that selector for some reason.

I have nothing else in the CSS code, just this.

Comment: First child only targets the first child of the parent, regardless of element. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/css-first-child-versus-first-of-type The sidebar works because the sidebar is the actual first child of the parent

Comment: @Huangism Thanks, how can I solve this. Any answer/example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to target? If you are trying to get `rightside` then just use `#rightside`

Comment: I try to border the first div child inside both #rightside and #sidebar

Comment: Then you need a space `#rightside :first-child { }` that will target the first child, if you need the div then you need to look at the question I linked which targets by type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#rightside div:first-child 
{
  /* styles */
}

#sidebar div:first-child 
{
  /* styles */
}
```

This way you apply your styles to the first DIV inside of `#rightside` and `#sidebar`.

**Because of comments**: this will only work if your first-child is actually a div, if you want to style the first-child regardless of it's type you can use:

```
#sidebar :first-child
{  
  /* styles */
}
```

Comment: `div:first-child` does not guarantee it will target a div

Comment: It works' I put . instead of :. Thanks!. It's like reading it from right to left: the first child DIV of the #sidebar.

Comment: If your code has stuff before the div then it will not work, you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Comment: @Huangism This applies only if the first-child is a div, thats correct. I thought that was what he wanted to achieve.

Comment: @Doodlebunch having that `div` in front of the `:first-child` is pointless

Comment: @Huangism It's not, sorry. In some cases you need it.

Comment: @Doodlebunch Thanks, answer accepted. Clear and easy to understand for a newbie like me.

Comment: Depending on how the rest of the HTML is structured, a child selector (`#rightside>div:first-child`) may be needed here to avoid the styles being to every `div` within `rightside` that happens to be the `:first-child` of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

For `#rightside:first-child` to work, the `div` with ID `rightside` would need to be the first child of the parent, as the `div` with ID `sidebar` is.

Given that you're using IDs, the `div` with ID `rightside` should be the only one in your HTML so the selector you'd use would be simply `#rightside`.

Answer (score 1):

You need this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

This targets the first type of a particular element, in your case it is a `div`

```
#rightside div:first-of-type {
    background-color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/w0wprkb0/

Comment: Thanks, I've read that it's less supported. I think better to use first-child (?)

Comment: You can see the support for it on the docs page I linked to see if it fits the bill or not. If your html have other elements before the div, then I would suggest you add a class to the item you want to target because you cannot target it with `div:first-child`

Comment: The DIV will be the first element.