# CSS :first-child and :first-of-type (example)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm still in the process of learning the difference between :first-child and :first-of-type pseudo classes using live examples.

I copied some HTML/CSS code from another website added it to: http://codepen.io/muygalan/pen/RroQNp.

Question:
When I remove the following code from my CSS file:

```
#blog article:first-of-type {
background: green;
}
```

Why doesn't the text nested within the `<article>` tag turn red?

Isn't...

```
#blog article:first-child {
color: red;
}
```

...supposed to turn the text color red if the previous :first-of-type has been removed from the code?

Comment: The selector `article:first-child` isn't selecting anything because that `article` element isn't the first child element (the `<header>` is the first child). The `:first-of-type` pseudo-class will select the first element by its *type*, which is why the `article:first-of-type` set the background to green.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/css-first-child-versus-first-of-type) clear things up for you?

Comment: @JoshCrozier made sense of my confusion. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's a great explanation on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-nth-child-and-nth-of-type/). Basically, the first child of the `#blog` `div` is not an `article` element; it's a `header` element. `:first-child` will match an element if it's the first element in the parent container. `:first-of-type` will match an element if it's the first element of its type in the parent container regardless of whether or not there are other elements preceding it.