# Select first-of-type class after using a not() selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm attempting to select the first item from a group, however I want to exclude certain items from the selection by class.

e.g. In this example, I attempt to select the first `.item` that doesn't have the `.hide` class. The `not()` works, correctly selecting all but the first item, however following `first-of-type` doesn't seem to match anything.

To clarify, in this example I'm aiming for:

- 1st item should remain red
- 2nd item (The first `.item` without the `.hide` class) should be blue
- 3rd item: Green
- 4th item: Green
- 5th item: Red
- 6th item: Green

```css
.item {
  background-color: #060;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
.hide {
  background-color: #600;
}
/* The important bit */
.item:not(.hide):first-of-type {
  background-color: #006;
}
```

```html
<div class="item hide">1</div>
<div class="item">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item hide">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
```

Am I writing the selector incorrectly? Is there an alternative way to do this?

Comment: "Am I writing the selector incorrectly?" You are, but depending on your situation you may or may not even be able to write a correct selector for this - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector

Comment: The fifth item should also be red, right? Since it has the `.hide` class.

Comment: please post some examples and what should be their expected colours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### The code

This code has the desired effect :

```css
.item {
    background-color: #006;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}

.hide {
    background-color: #600;
}

.item:not(.hide) ~ .item:not(.hide) {
    background-color: #060;
}
```

```html
<div class="item hide">1</div>
<div class="item hide">2</div>
<div class="item">3</div>
<div class="item">4</div>
<div class="item hide">5</div>
<div class="item">6</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/7LaenLus/11/))

Comment: Apologies I didn't make myself clear, but there may be multiple `.hide` items and I only want to affect the first instance of this.

Comment: @DBS : Check out my updated code. Does it now match your criteria?

Comment: Perfect, I couldn't get my head around a way to do that. Thanks! (I'll accept the answer as soon as It lets me)

Answer (score 1):

As all your items are divs, if they are the only children in their parent then `:first-of-type` is equivalent to `:first-child`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type/24657721#24657721) for more details.

Since [you can't directly match the first child with a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/can-i-combine-nth-child-or-nth-of-type-with-an-arbitrary-selector) (or any other sub-selector) you will need to do this another way, using an overriding rule.

The simplest way to do this is to:

1. Make all items blue.
2. Make `.hide` items red (as intended).
3. Apply the green styles to `.item:not(.hide) ~ .item:not(.hide)`. That is, [all items that don't have the `.hide` class, that follow the first such item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107).

This accounts for all possible cases with just *one* assumption: that if the first element doesn't have the `.hide` class then it should be blue as well:

```css
.item {
  background-color: #006;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
}
.hide {
  background-color: #600;
}
.item:not(.hide) ~ .item:not(.hide) {
  background-color: #060;
}
section {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="item hide">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item hide">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="item hide">1</div>
    <div class="item hide">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item hide">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item hide">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item hide">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
</section>
```

If the first element may lack the `.hide` class, but you only want the first `.item:not(.hide)` **after** a `.hide` item to be blue, then it becomes impossible without JavaScript.