# Apply a CSS rule to an element if it only occurs once in a parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given:

```
 <h2>Header Line 1</h2>
 <h2>Header Line 2</h2>
```

I know that I access the second h2 and can apply some spacing below that element by doing:

```
h2 + h2 {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

However, some of my sections only contain a single header line like:

```
<h2>Catchy Tagline!</h2>
```

Can I selectively access and apply something like `padding-bottom: 20px;` to the `h2:first-child` ***when there is only one `h2` element***?

Otherwise, I would be adding a 20px space between any/all `h2` tags and I want them to stay set at 0 margin/padding if they are stacked as my first example shows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `:only-of-type`:

```
h2:only-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

If you need to apply the style only when the lone `h2` is the first child, you should not *replace* the `:first-child` with `:only-of-type` but add it so you have both pseudo-classes:

```
h2:first-child:only-of-type {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Is `only-of-type` supported by all modern browsers? I have never seen that pseudo-class before.

Comment: @armadadrive: Yes, if you've seen :first-of-type, :only-of-type was introduced at the same time and is not new, and support is identical.

Comment: I just had a brief look at the MDN entry - would `first-child` be redundant in this case?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it seems to me that only-of-type would find nothing if a child had siblings?

Comment: @armadadrive: It wouldn't always be redundant - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type/24657721#24657721) for an illustration (it says :first-of-type, but you can treat :only-of-type as equivalent to :first-of-type:last-of-type).

Comment: @armadadrive: Or, more succinctly: consider a div that contains a p and a span. The p and span are each the only siblings of their type, but they are siblings of one another - the p is the first child, and the span, the last.

Comment: Oh! I've been thinking of last-child incorrectly and it just happened to work in most cases. If I do: `p:last-child` but it's followed by a <ul>, say, that won't work because it's not the last child?