# Doesn't CSS first-child or last-child work with class wise?

Tags: html, css

Maybe this question is ridiculous, but I want to know this fact. I have a `li` element with two classes (see below), but it is not working as I expected. Does anybody know the reason?

```css
.red:first-child {
    color:#F00;
}
.blue:first-child {
    color:#00F; /* not working */
}
.red:last-child {
    color:#F00; /* not working */
}
.blue:last-child {
    color:#00F; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="red">one</li> <!-- This is the first child of red -->
    <li class="red">two</li>
    <li class="red">three</li>
    <li class="blue">one</li> <!-- and this first child of blue -->
    <li class="blue">two</li>
    <li class="blue">three</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Its working as expected. `<li class="blue">one</li>` is not the `first-child` of parent `ul`

Comment: @Satpal: no its not working as expected...

Comment: third one `<li class="red">three</li>` should also change the color

Comment: that is last-child @RahulSharma

Comment: exactly..i was talking on the behalf of `<li>`

Comment: Problem exists in wrong understanding of `:first-child` or `:last-child` selector. They will select any element only when an element is first or last child element of its parent respectively.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman can you give me any reference please ?

Comment: Your selector `.blue:first-child` is not working because `.blue` is not first child of parent. This is the thinking behind implementation of this selector and as for me its quite logical.

Comment: @Naila Here is the [Official Documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#structural-pseudos) from W3 for pseudo selectors.

Comment: down voters please tell me the reason too

Comment: @Naila child is suppose to link to parent..in normal way if you have 1 son then if there will be any it will treated like nth son so there will be only first child in one parent.. you can have multi first child in one parent.. same logic is in coding implement..and bdw m not downvoter.

Comment: @Naila: Everyone has given you the answer but you seem dissatisfied. So it's not exactly clear what your *real* question is. Are you asking why :first-child isn't matching the first .blue element, or why it was *designed* that way?

Comment: i have satisfied with comment of @Leo the lion

Comment: isn't :first-child, :last-child, :nth-child referred to the parent element, in this case the ul element?

Comment: @mnemosdev: It describes the child element *relative to* its parent. It does not describe the parent element.

Comment: @BoltClock so ul:first-child would be the red class li and red:first-child would ref to itself?

Comment: @mnemosdev: No, ul:first-child matches the ul in much the same way ul.example (with a class selector) matches the ul. It doesn't match other elements. Likewise, .red:first-child matches whichever element has the .red class, not its parent, or its child.

Comment: @mnemosdev: So in a ul with several li elements, li:first-child matches the first li. Whether ul:first-child matches that ul depends on whether that ul is the first child of its own parent, which is outside the scope of this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As others have mentioned, :first-child is working as expected, as the first child of the parent.

> The :first-child selector is used to select the specified selector, only if it is the first child of its parent.

Source: [CSS :first-child Selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp)

You can reach the first .blue like this:

```
.red + .blue
```

or if you want to get all the .blue after .red

```
.red ~ .blue
```

You might want to use [:first-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_first-of-type.asp) which selects the first of a type but then those .blue would have to be a different HTML element.

```css
div.red:first-of-type {
    color:#F00;
}
div.red:last-of-type {
    color:#00F;
}
p.blue:first-of-type {
    color:#F00;
}
p.blue:last-of-type {
    color:#00F; 
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="red">one</div>
    <div class="red">two</div>
    <div class="red">three</div>
    <p class="blue">one</p>
    <p class="blue">two</p>
    <p class="blue">three</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope. :first-of-type doesn't look at the class either.

Comment: You are right @BoltClock, it doesn't. There is no option to do so with class as far as I know. You could however reach the first blue with those other selectors I included in the answer.

Comment: I agree. I do think that :first-of-type shouldn't even be considered since a ul can only have li as children (which means [both pseudo-classes will always match the same element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type/24657721#24657721)), and I just personally don't like changing the HTML to fit a CSS selector. But I removed my downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Because It consider Li list. First you have to mention first-childs so take first command to show red. THen Take last code as blue last-child so take last code to show blue.

It not consider the red and blue class orders. It consider li list and periorities.

Comment: that is my question, why its not considering the class wise

Comment: It consider only the paren and child elements like ul as parent and li as child. Not taking class.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because what you said to the browser was (for the red case, the blue one is similar):

1. Locate all elements `.red`.
2. From that list of `.red` elements, pick the first one (`first-child`).
3. Apply the red color to it.

The browser works as expected and apply the red color to the first element of the list.

**EDIT:**

The blue case is due to the fact that CSS always looks for the most precise rule. If both rules has the same precision level, the last one wins, so in this case, the last `.blue:last-child` wins and the `.blue:first-child` is ignored.

Comment: "the blue one is similar" And that's why the asker *expects* .blue:first-child to match the first .blue element. But it doesn't.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read it, "mea culpa". In that case, both selectors has the same "precision level", I mean, they aren't more precise than each other, so "the last one" rule applies and the one colored is the last blue.

Comment: This has nothing to do with specificity. Specificity does not preclude both .blue:first-child and .blue:last-child matching different elements (or the same element) at the same time.

Comment: @BoltClock You are right. Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/egOPRx) with the order changed.