# Why `nth-of-type` behaves differently in different browser versions?

Tags: selenium, css-selectors, automated-tests, ui-automation

### Problem:

So I've run into a peculiar difference in behavior of `:nth-of-type` selector when applied to an element with tag type not being specified in selector.

Take the following **HTML**:

```
<div class="parent-class">
    <header>...</header>
    <div class="child-class">...</div>
    <div class="child-class">...</div>
</div>
```

Now, this selector

```
.parent-class .child-class:nth-of-type(1)
```

should probably point to the first child `div` element, which it does in **Chrome 59** and **Firefox 54**, but does not in Mink-drived Selenium browsers (**Chrome 53** from selenium/hub:3.0.1-fermium and **Firefox 50**  from selenium/node-firefox-debug:2.53.0).

What `nth-of-type` does in those browsers is ignoring element types altogether - meaning, for selector to work one has to specify either:

```
.parent-class .child-class:nth-of-type(2)
```

or

```
.parent-class div.child-class:nth-of-type(1)
```

**Question:**

Why does the element type gets ignored in case of Selenium browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is a limitation of Symfony's `CssSelector` component which is used by Mink

Mink uses `CssSelector` to translate elements to `xpath` which is interpretable by the driver.

And this tool simply does not fully support several types of CSS selectors, which is actually stated in the [official documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/css_selector.html):

> Several pseudo-classes are not yet supported:
>
> *:first-of-type, *:last-of-type, *:nth-of-type, *:nth-last-of-type, *:only-of-type. **(These work with an element name (e.g. li:first-of-type) but not with *.**

Answer (score 2):

Selenium is not known to have issues with `:nth-of-type()`. Perhaps it's a bug with Mink, since that behavior is clearly incorrect — `:nth-of-type()` should not require a type selector to work, as stated in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type/24657721#24657721).

Comment: Thanks, but your answer was not enough for me, so I've made an investigation - see my answer. You are right - it is the tool's fault, but actually Symfony's.

Comment: @BVengerov: Glad you were able to track it down.