# non-classified element interrupts targeted styling of child of classified elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

I'm trying to style first and last child, inside span with a specific class.
It doesn't matter if I use `>` or not in my CSS,
This code won't work unless I remove the first and the last `DIV`, even though they are unrelated to the class I'm trying to target.

Why?

CSS:

```
.parent-span .cta-wrapper {background:gray;}
.parent-span:last-child > .cta-wrapper {background:red;   } 
.parent-span:first-child > .cta-wrapper {background:green}
```

HTML:

```
<div>xxxxxxxxx</div>

<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
</span>


<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
</span>      


<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</span>


<div>xxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## nth CSS Selectors

When using nth CSS selectors, we must take certain things into consideration:

**Hint #1** - The ***ancestor*** element that all of the target elements have in ***common***.

**Hint #2** - Each of the target elements' **`tagName`s** and their ancestors as well.

**Hint #3** - The **`nth`** ***point of entry*** which isn't always the target elements. It could possibly                be more than one level depending if the target element and/or ancestor elements                have sibling elements or not and how they are positioned.

### Hierarchy

The layout is a 5 level hierarchy.

1. **ROOT** ---- tagName: `<html>`
2. **LEVEL 0** - tagName: `<head>`, ***`<body>`*** - Role: **`<<<COMMON ANCESTOR>>>`**
3. **LEVEL 1** - tagName: `<div>`, ***`<span>`*** -- Role: **`<<<POINT OF ENTRY>>>`**
4. **LEVEL 2** - tagName: ***`<div>`*** -------------- Role: **`<<<TARGET ELEMENT>>>`**
5. **LEVEL 3** - tagName: `<div>`

### Two `nth`'s - `nth-child` and `nth-of-type`

#### `nth-child:`

- If you use `nth-child`, ignore **hint #2**,
- So at the ***point of entry*** the ***common ancestor*** (i.e. `<body>`) has **5 children**, not 3 children.
- The line-up is: `<div>`, `<span>`, `<span>`, `<span>`, `<div>`
- So instead of `first-child` it should be `nth-child(2)`
- Instead of `last-child`, it's `nth-child(4)`

### `nth-of-type:`

- If you use `nth-of-type`, **Hint #2** is key to understanding how to use `nth-of-type`.
- At the ***point of entry*** the ***common ancestor*** has 2 `<div>`s and 3 `<span>`s.
- Now we can specify a `<span>` as first, last, etc. because `nth-of-type` differentiates between element `tagName`s.
- [common ancestor]................:`body`
- {direct descendant(a.k.a. child)}:`>`
- [point of entry].................: `span:first-of-type`
- [target element].................: `div`
- `body>span:first-of-type div`

Of course the selector above can have variations, but the important part is the ***point of entry* `span:first-of-type`.**

#### Demo

**Click any span and it will revert from `display:block` to `display:inline` which is what was posted in OP**

**Hover over any element to see its Level in the hierarchy, its `tagName`, and what its role is.**

**There is a version of `nth-child` styles commented out included as well.***

```js
// For demonstration purposes
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span')).forEach(function(spn, idx) {
  spn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    spn.classList.toggle('inline');
  }, false);
});
```

```css
:root::before {
  content: 'ROOT';
}

html {
  height: 111vh;
  width: 90vw;
  background: rgba(255, 200, 50, 0.2);
  font: 600 15px/1 Consolas;
  cursor: crosshair;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}

body {
  height: 101%;
  width: 50vw;
  padding: 0 10vw;
  margin: 2vh auto;
  outline: 0.5rem solid rgba(250, 150, 150, 0.9);
  background: rgba(50, 255, 0, 0.4);
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

div {
  max-height: 15vh;
  max-width: 50vw;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 2px dashed darkblue;
  background: rgba(255, 200, 50, 0.5);
}

span {
  /* OP: display:inline */
  display: block;
  min-height: 10%;
  max-width: 50vw;
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 8px auto;
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 100, 0.7);
}

.inline {
  display: inline;
}


/*::..BEGIN DISABLED OP..::
.parent-span .cta-wrapper {background:gray;}
.parent-span:last-child > .cta-wrapper {background:red;   } 
.parent-span:first-child > .cta-wrapper {background:green}
}
::..END DISABLED OP..::*/

/*::..BEGIN nth-type-of..::*/
body>span>div {
  background: gray;
}

body>span:first-of-type>div {
  background: red;
}

body>span:last-of-type>div {
  background: green;
}
/*::..END nth-of-type..::*/

/*::..BEGIN nth-child..::
body>span>div {
  background: gray;
}

body>span:nth-child(2)>div {
  background: red;
}

body>span:nth-child(4)>div {
  background: green;
}
::..END nth-child..::*/
```

```html
<html title='ROOT-HTML'>

<head title='L0-HEAD'>

</head>

<body title='L0-BODY [COMMON ANCESTOR]'>L0

  <div title='L1-DIV'>[XXXX] L1 [XXXX]</div>

  <span class="parent-span" title='L1-SPAN [POINT OF ENTRY]'>L1
    <div class="cta-wrapper" title='L2-DIV [TARGET ELEMENT]'>L2
        <div title='L3-DIV'>L3 [1]</div>
    </div>
</span>

  <span class="parent-span" title='L1-SPAN [POINT OF ENTRY]'>L1
    <div class="cta-wrapper" title='L2-DIV [TARGET ELEMENT]'>L2
        <div title='L3-DIV'>L3 [2]</div>
    </div>
</span>

  <span class="parent-span" title='L1-SPAN [POINT OF ENTRY]'>L1
    <div class="cta-wrapper" title='L2-DIV [TARGET ELEMENT]'>L2
        <div title='L3-DIV'>L3 [3]</div>
    </div>
</span>

  <div title='L1-DIV'>[XXXX] L1 [XXXX]</div>

</body>

</html>
```

The terms: ***common ancestor™***, ***point of entry™***, ***role™***, and ***hierarchy™*** are not standard terms, they are of my own creation because these rules are never explained very well AFAIK by anyone (myself included).

Comment: thanks! very informative. yet I'm not sure I understand what is the role of classes within all the these? do classes ever help with targeting when we have "different levels", or do they help only once the desired level was already targeted, using the other rules?

Comment: People just overcomplicate how the :nth-* pseudos work. It really doesn't get any simpler than ":nth-child() matches the element when it's the nth child of its parent for the given n", e.g. I'm the third and youngest child in my family, which makes me :nth-child(3):last-child. That said, what do you think of my explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type) of :first-child vs :first-of-type?

Comment: @rockyraw: The classes are there to give you an idea of what *purpose* these elements serve. You don't need to use them for hierarchical selection, but on the other hand, many style guides actually recommend creating classes specifically to make elements easier to target. You end up with a lot of what are called utility classes, which are either good or bad depending on your requirements, and your personal preferences.

Comment: @rockyraw Good question, I left the classes out to emphasize the predominate role `tagName`s and hierarchy have in determining the target. In general if you go the path of the `nth` then `#id`, `.classes`, `[attribute]`s are secondary. The reason why I included this ***common ancestor™*** idea is to convey the idea that it can be repeated if you happen to have several levels that split off to many siblings. As long as you have a common point at every split where siblings come from it's easier to think that way because `.class`es, `#id`s can get confusing when using `nth`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `last-of-type` and `first-of-type` instead of `last-child` and `first-child`

The `last-child` / `first-child` address and count ALL siblings of the parent element: divs, spans, p etc.

The `last-of-type` / `first-of-type` selectors address only the one TYPE (the tag, not the class), i.e. the divs OR the spans OR the p tags etc.

```css
.parent-span .cta-wrapper {
  background: gray;
}

.parent-span:last-of-type>.cta-wrapper {
  background: red;
}

.parent-span:first-of-type>.cta-wrapper {
  background: green
}
```

```html
<div>xxxxxxxxx</div>

<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
</span>


<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
</span>


<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</span>


<div>xxxxxxxxx</div>
```

Comment: Johannes I've read your explanation about `first-child` and `last-child` but I still don't understand why it doesn't work. When I test PO code with this simple css `span:first-child {background-color:green;}` this selector doesn't work either.

Comment: hm... it seems a div inside span don't inherit css from its parent, even `span {background-color:green;}` don't work with PO code.

Answer (score 0):

In order for first-child and last-child pseudos to work your html content needs to be inside a list or some other series of items. Your spans are singular and so there's no first and last item.

See the unordered list I created and the styling to select first and last list item there.

In order for you to do this, put your spans in a div with the parent class, then select that parent div and then a first-child/last-child for a repeating element inside.

```css
.parent-span .cta-wrapper {background:gray;}
.parent-span:last-child > .cta-wrapper {background:red;   } 
.parent-span:first-child > .cta-wrapper {background:green}

ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 2em 0 0 0;
padding: 0;
}

ul.parent-span li:first-child 
{
background:green;
}

ul.parent-span li:last-child 
{
background:red;
}
```

```html
<div>xxxxxxxxx</div>

<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
</span>


<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
</span>      


<span class="parent-span">
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
</span>

<ul class="parent-span">
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>


<div>xxxxxxxxx</div>
```