# first-child not selecting the first of its type

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi,

I am having problems with first-child selector. This is my html code

```
<div> 
 <div></div>
 <article class="portfolio"></article>
 <article class="portfolio"></article>
 <article class="portfolio"></article>
</div>
```

I want to select the first `article` from the list so I do this

```
article.portfolio:first-child {}
```

but it wont work. Only if I remove the `div` above it it will select it. I thought `first-child` would select the first ARTICLE from inside the parent `div` but instead its counting the `div` above it as the first child.

What kind I do so first-child selects considering only the articles while ignoring all other element types?

Thank you.

Comment: You're looking for `article:first-of-type { ... }`

Comment: will that select the first article of its parent or the first of the whole document?

Comment: It will select the first `<article>` element in every section. You can do `article.portfolio:first-of-type` if need be.

Comment: See this post for all about `first-of-type` vs `first-child` and their limitations: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type (linked to from my answer to the above question) which actually focuses on the difference between these two pseudos specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no element that has that class and is the first child. If you want the first element with that class, use `.portfolio:first-of-type`.

Comment: great, is there a second-of-type and so on?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

Comment: Thank you! I should have figured that out!