# Show breadcrumb with text-overflow css

Tags: html, css, breadcrumbs

I have a breadcrumb which I need to cut / shorten the breadcrumb if it's too long with `text-overflow` css. I have tried and confused to make a different color link only in last breadcrumb. In my breadcrumb, max breadcrumb to show is 4.

From the code below, I success to shortened breadcrumb using `text-overflow: ellipsis`. Like if breadcrumb have 4 link, I using `foreach` to show `breadcrumb` that `index number 2` and `index number 3` is too long, I shortened them using `text-overflow: ellipsis`. If the breadcrumb have 3 link, I used same `looping` too.

I want to ask how can I make different color text / link only in the last breadcrumb like if breadcrumb have 3 link, `index number 2` is have different color than others. And if breadcrumb have 4 link, `index number 3` is have different color ?

Here's the html code

```
 <?php if (isset($breadcrumbs)): ?>
    <?php 
      $numItems = count($breadcrumbs);
      $i = 0;
      //echo $numItems;
    ?>
 <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
     <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb): ?>    
             <?php if ($i == 0 || $i == 1): ?>
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= $breadcrumb['url'] ?>"><?= $breadcrumb['text'] ?></a></li>
             <?php else: ?>
                  <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?= $breadcrumb['url'] ?>"  class="last"><?= $breadcrumb['text'] ?> </a></li>
             <?php endif ?>
             <?php $i++; ?>
         <?php endforeach ?>
     </ol>
  </nav>
 <?php endif ?>
```

Here's the css code

```
 .breadcrumb {
   padding: 5px 0px;
   margin-bottom: 0px;
   background-color: #ecf0f5; 
 }
.breadcrumb-item+.breadcrumb-item::before {
   content: ">";
   font-size: 12px;
 }
.breadcrumb-item {
   font-size: 14px;
 }
.breadcrumb-item .last{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100px;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   line-height: 10px;
}
.breadcrumb-item a{
  color: #535353;
}
.breadcrumb-item:hover > a{
  color: #1787fa
}
.mini-breadcrumb{
  display: none;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this css on your `.breadcrumb-item`:

```
.breadcrumb-item:last-of-type a{
  color: grey;
}
```

use your desired color instead of `grey`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [:last-child](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp) selector.

```
.breadcrumb-item:last-child a {
  color: grey;
}
```

Just adding another link where you can find difference between type-of and child difference.

[What is the difference between :first-child and :first-of-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657555/what-is-the-difference-between-first-child-and-first-of-type)