# Matching the first/nth element of a certain type in the entire document

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I specify `:first-of-type` of the entire document?

I want to style the first `<p>` of the HTML, no mater where it is located (I don't want to write `section p:first-of-type` because it may be located elsewhere in a different HTML document).

```css
p {
  background:red; 
}

p:first-of-type {
  background:pink;
}

p:last-of-type {
  background:yellow; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p>111</p>
    <p>222</p>
    <p>333</p>
  </section>
  <p>444</p>
  <p>555</p>
</body>
```

Comment: Could you not just give the first one a class and assign the css to  that?

Comment: I'm afraid that it is not possible to achieve that with pure CSS. You have to get your hands dirty with JavaScript :-)

Comment: would you mind repharsing your question ... I'm not sure I understand properly ... in the example you gave what's the color order you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Are you looking for the selector `*` ?

Comment: @henser The question is clear enough, the OP wants to target the first paragraph element no matter where it is located within the document.

Comment: As a side-note: `<section>` semantic element is not a generic container and should contain at least a heading.

Answer (score 7):

With CSS alone this unfortunately isn't possible. The documentation for the `:first-of-type` pseudo-class [states](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#first-of-type-pseudo):

> The `:first-of-type` pseudo-class represents an element that is the first sibling of its type in the list of children of its parent element.

This means that `:first-of-type` is applied to the first element of its type relative to its parent and not the document's root (or the `body` element, in this case).

---

### JavaScript solutions

#### `:first-of-type`

We can achieve this by introducing some JavaScript. All we need for this is JavaScript's `querySelector()` method, which pulls the first matching element from the selector specified.

In this example I've altered your `:first-of-type` pseudo-class to instead be a class of "first-of-type", then used JavaScript to add this class to the element returned when using `querySelector('p')`:

```js
document.querySelector('p').className += ' first-of-type';
```

```css
p {
  background:red; 
}


p.first-of-type {
  background: pink;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p>111</p>
    <p>222</p>
    <p>333</p>
  </section>
  <p>444</p>
  <p>555</p>
</body>
```

#### `:nth-child` and `:last-of-type`

As for `:nth-child` and `:last-of-type`, we can instead make use of a similar method JavaScript gives us: `querySelectorAll()`. This method pulls *all* matching elements into a NodeList (which is similar to an array), which we can then iterate through or select specific elements from within through the index:

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('p');

// nth-of-type = NodeList[n - 1]
// e.g. to select the 3rd p element ("333"):
if (elems.length >= 2)
   elems[2].className += ' nth-of-type';

// last-of-type = NodeList length - 1
if (elems.length)
   elems[elems.length - 1].className += ' last-of-type';
```

```css
p {
  background:red; 
}


p.nth-of-type {
  background: pink;
}

p.last-of-type {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
    <p>111</p>
    <p>222</p>
    <p>333</p>
  </section>
  <p>444</p>
  <p>555</p>
</body>
```

Note that I've included `if` statements around both selectors to ensure the elems NodeList has enough elements, otherwise an error will be thrown.

Comment: For the fastest solution, i would prefer js too, dont waste time searching, use js instead

Comment: To get the nth matching element simply index off querySelectorAll: `var elements = document.querySelectorAll('p'); elements[elements.length - 1].className += ' last';`

Comment: @BoltClock seems I'd completely neglected to respond to that part of the question! I'll update my answer.

Comment: Is there any chance that this feature will be added on the CSS4 spec?

Comment: @Vandervals based on the current state of the [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) Working Draft it doesn't look like something which will be added unfortunately.

Comment: I am considering marking [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751127/select-first-second-or-third-element-with-given-class-name) I answered several years before as a duplicate of the one you've answered here. All but two of the answers there (one of which is not my own) misinterpreted the question (one going so far as to take the code sample completely literally), and frankly the question isn't nearly as well-written or clear as the one here, though in fairness this one was edited heavily by you and Hashem.