# How to select nth element of the same type

Tags: javascript, css, dom, css-selectors

I would like to select the nth `td` from all of the `td`, how do I do that?

I know I can do it with `document.querySelectorAll("td")[nth]`, but I'm looking for a pure css way.

I tried `document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(77)")`, but it doesn't give the result as `document.querySelectorAll("td")[77]` does.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> I know I can do it with `document.querySelectorAll("td")[nth]`, but I'm looking for a pure css way.

There is no pure CSS equivalent. See [Matching the first/nth element of a certain type in the entire document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524415/matching-the-first-nth-element-of-a-certain-type-in-the-entire-document)

Answer (score 40):

```js
var result = document.querySelectorAll("table td:nth-of-type(2)");

console.log(result);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>nope</td><td>nope</td></tr>
  <tr><td>nope</td><td>here</td></tr>
  
</table>
```

UP. Snippet shows that you cannot select TD elements globally, but you can get nth td element in given TR. Is this what you are looking for?

there is selector `:nth-of-type(77)`

should help you.

`nth-child` selector counts all children of given element - including other types of tags. Also css selector counts from 1, when JS `querySelector` result `array` from 0

Comment: I tried querySelectorAll("td:nth-of-type(77)"), but it returns the result as querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(77)"), just empty list.

Answer (score 2):

There is a pure css way named ==> :nth-of-type
For example to select the 77th td element of each parent in the document the syntax is

`td:nth-of-type(77)`

For more information about the :nth-of-type selector see the Morzilla developer network if these links will break let me know in a comment below.

//For the element it self see //
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type

//For syntax about all the selections you can make with :nth-child and :nth-of-type see //
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

Comment: For the purposes of links not working for future readers try to post some code examples in your answer

Comment: This is wrong. The documentation says "nth number of child of its parent element", so you're only getting the nth in a given parent, not the whole document.

Comment: @Ehsan Kia I've updated the answer to be more exact in it's explaination.