# CSS selector to select first and last element under parent, when html structure is not deterministic

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have following `HTML` structure. Is it possible to select first and last `my-item` element under `parent` element purely by `CSS`?

`row` in which `my-item` element is can be wrapped in other `div`s and (Angular) `component` elements. Also `component` elements can be nested within each other. This is `HTML` structure is generated based on current page.

In JavaScript I would accomplish this by selecting all `my-item` elements under `parent` as a flat list and selecting a first and last of them.

**UPDATE:** 
Update `HTML` template to more resemble my actual page content.

```js
var parentElement = document.querySelector('.parent');
var myItems = parentElement.querySelectorAll('.my-item');

var firstItem = myItems[0];
var lastItem = myItems[myItems.length-1];

firstItem.classList.add('red-background');
lastItem.classList.add('red-background');
```

```css
.red-background {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <person-component>
        <div class="template">
            <div class="row">
                <component-row-template>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Select me!</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                    </div>
                </component-row-template>
                <component-row-template>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                    </div>
                </component-row-template>
            </div>
            <div class="row-separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <component-row-template>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                    </div>
                </component-row-template>
            </div>
        </div>
    </person-component>
    <div class="row-separator"></div>
    <organization-component>
        <div class="template">
            <div class="row">
                <component-row-template>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                    </div>
                </component-row-template>
            </div>
            <div class="row-separator"></div>
            <div class="row">
                <component-row-template>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                    </div>
                </component-row-template>
            </div>
            <div class="row-separator"></div>
            <person-component>
                <div class="template">
                    <div class="row">
                        <component-row-template>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                            </div>
                        </component-row-template>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <component-row-template>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
                            </div>
                        </component-row-template>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </person-component>
        </div>
    </organization-component>
    <div class="row-separator"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <row-template>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
            </div>
        </row-template>
    </div>
    <div class="row-separator"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <row-template>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="my-item">Select me!</div>
            </div>
        </row-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess there is no pure css solution if you don't like to explictly traverse the DOM with css. See this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41848550/how-to-select-nth-element-of-the-same-type

Answer (score 1):

The below code can work with the assumption that every child div of the parent has the desired ".my-item" and the every ".my-item" is inside a ".col".

It will select the first and the last div from the direct siblings of ".parent" and then will try to find the first and last ".col" and apply the rule to the ".my-item" inside them.

```
.parent > div:last-of-type .col:last-of-type .my-item, 
.parent > div:first-of-type .col:first-of-type .my-item  {
  background-color: red;
}
```

If that's not the case and you really don't know anything about the html structure at all, then I am afraid that CSS cannot help you..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Nasia, I wanted to make example as simple as possible, but looks like I didn't included enough complexity. My real HTML is wrapped in custom elements (angular components like `<person-detail>` so I can't count on `.parent` containing children of only certain type like `div`. Sorry for that, I will update my example. But I feel like there is no way to achieve what I want just by CSS.

Comment: Oh, I see.. yes, unfortunately css is not able to go through the dom like this.. When you find yourself in such cases that you cannot cover with a simple css rule that feels like unnecessarily complicated html structure. Maybe you wanna check on this first and have a 'dry' approach

Answer (score 1):

*Assuming that all `.my-item`s are always wrapped inside a `.col` that is in turn wrapped inside at least another `div (section)` and that each section has only one `.row`* (assumption taken from your example), yes it is possible to achieve what you want using a purely CSS approach. The approach is:

- Select `.parent`, as we're only interested only in selecting `.my-item` inside this element
- As all `.my-item`s always have a `div` container (whether it be a nested container with class `section` or simply inside a `row` container), we can specifically determine which wrapper containers are the first and last. These first and last containers, respectively, **must be** the container in which the first and last `my-item` are contained.
- As all `.section` container only has one `.row`, you can easily get the first and last `.col` of each `.section`. This means that to get the first `.my-item`, simply select the first `.col` and from the first `.section` wrapper and apply the style to `.my-item`. Same logic works for your last `.my-item`.

Here is a minimal working example below:

```js
let firstChild = document.querySelector('.parent > div:first-child .col:first-child .my-item')
let lastChild = document.querySelector('.parent > div:last-child .col:last-child .my-item')
console.log(firstChild, lastChild)
```

```css
.parent > div:first-child .col:first-child .my-item {
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
}

.parent > div:last-child .col:last-child .my-item {
  background: red;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="main-section">
    <div class="section-wrapper">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <div class="my-item">Select me!</div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="section-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="my-item">Not me</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="my-item">Select me!</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As mentioned, this code works if the above assumption is true. One easy example of when this code will break would be when there may be more that two `.row`s existing in one `section`-like wrapper.

Comment: Thanks Richard for your example, my real HTML is a more complicated than example I provided and there can be more `row`s within section wrapper. Sorry for not being explicit about that. I will update the example in question.

Comment: @mimo Try to cover all cases of what your HTML may be. This will help to generate more accurate results, if a CSS approach is indeed possible.

Comment: @mimo I don't think that it's possible to select what you want using pure CSS. If there is though, I still think that JS is a better solution for your case. Alternatively, if you can control the HTML structure, you can add a specific class for the first and last `.my-item`.