# trying to use query selector to select a specific child in a html document

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

site i am selecting from looks roughly like this

```
<div class="start-left">
    ...
    <div class="news-post">...</div>
    <div class="news-post">...</div>
    <!-- want to get this one above -->
    <div class="news-post">...</div>
    <div class="news-post">...</div>
    <div class="news-post">...</div>
    <div class="news-post">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

tried this but didnt work on either firefox or chrome

```
document.querySelector('.start-left div:nth-child(2)')
```

is this even possible or do i need to rething how i am doing this? I am using puppeteer for a webscraper and need to be able to press a link in a specific news post, e.g the second one

Comment: It should work fine

Comment: you should use `querySelectorAll`. See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41848760/13460667

Comment: This worked for me on Chrome. Are you getting any kind of error message?

Comment: This works. Are you placing the code after the DOM, or using `defer`?

Comment: @KatharineOsborne it just returns null when trying it in a chrome session and on puppeteer it stops it as it cant find anything

Comment: Pretty sure it was just me bieng stupid, there were two other elements above the children that i failed to mention, adding two to the selector fixed the problem. Sorry for any inconveniences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nth-child(n)` counts all children of the element, regardless of the type of element (tag name). If there are other elements of different type coming before your target element `nth-child` will fail to find the correct element and may return null.

However, the selector [`nth-of-type(n)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type)

> matches elements based on their position among siblings of the same
> type (tag name)

and ignores elements of a different type.

```js
// nth-child(2) returns null because the 2nd element is not a div
var wrongElement = document.querySelector('.start-left div:nth-child(2)');
// nth-of-type(2) filters using the type of element
var correctElement = document.querySelector('.start-left div:nth-of-type(2)');
console.log('div:nth-child(2): ' + wrongElement);
console.log('div:nth-of-type(2): ' + correctElement.outerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="start-left">
    <p class="news-post">...</p>
    <p class="news-post">Not this</p>
    <div class="news-post">...</div>
    <div class="news-post">This one</div>
    <!-- want to get this one above -->
    <div class="news-post">...</div>        
</div>
```

You could use your work-around by adding the number of preceding elements to the selector, eg `nth-child(4)`, however, a more robust solution is to use `nth-of-type(2)`.