# Applying certain css only for the first occurrence in the html

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a html like below:

```
<div class="A"> --- Div 0 There can be multiple of this
    <div class="B C"></div>
</div>

<div class="A"> --- Div 1
    <div class="B C D"></div>
</div>
<div class="A"> --- Div 2
    <div></div>
    <div class="B C D"></div>
</div>
<div class="A"> --- Div 3
    <div class="B C D"></div>
</div>
```

I want certain styling to be applied to `<div class="B C D"></div>` only for Div 1.

I have used css **.B.C.D:first-of-type** for doing this, but it is also affecting Div 3.

I donot have control over HTML and want to resolve it only using CSS

Comment: if you really need just the first div to have certain css rules applied just add a secondary class to that div only.

Comment: Even if you don't have control over the HTML, surely you can make *some* assumptions about it? If you can't make any assumptions at all, then this is a duplicate of [Matching the first/nth element of a certain type in the entire document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524415/matching-the-first-nth-element-of-a-certain-type-in-the-entire-document)

Answer (score 2):

Use [:first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) to get first child among a group of elements. Try this:

```css
.A:first-child > div.B.C{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="A"> --- Div 0 There can be multiple of this
    <div class="B C">There can be multiple of this</div>
</div>

<div class="A"> --- Div 1
    <div class="B C D"></div>
</div>
<div class="A"> --- Div 2
    <div></div>
    <div class="B C D"></div>
</div>
<div class="A"> --- Div 3
    <div class="B C D"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: wouldnt .A:first-child > div already take only the div inside the first .A div element?

Comment: @mnemosdev, Modified :)

Comment: Actually you were right, no need to specify div:first-child. :)

Comment: Apologies, have modified my HTML, added div 0

Comment: Can u explain a bit more what you are trying to achieve? As per your question, above code snippet is working isnt it?