# Is there a CSS selector equivalent to JS querySelector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

EDIT: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class) is along a similar vein to my own, but it's not quite a duplicate because I understand how the pseudo-selectors of `:first-child` and `:first-of-type` actually work.  The question is not "Why are my selectors not working," but rather "What selector *besides* just plain `:first-child` can I use for my circumstance?"  The accepted answer of that question just explains information I already know.

===

In JavaScript, when you use `element.querySelector('a')`, it will return the first `<a>` tag it finds inside the element, no matter how deep, and it will not continue searching for more elements.

In CSS, you can use a space like `.element a`, and it will apply to every single `<a>` tag it finds inside the element, no matter how deep.  This is more similar to `element.querySelectorAll('a')` if you were to compare it to JavaScript.

Even `.element > a` applies to every `<a>` tag that is a direct child of the element, still not quite right *and* I'd rather not depend on the nesting level.  `.element a:first-child` is closer, but still not perfect.  This will *still* apply to multiple elements if your structure looks like this:

```html
<span class="element">
  <span>
    <a>Demo</a> <!-- I only want to select this one -->
    <a>Demo</a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a>Demo</a>
    <a>Demo</a>
  </span>
</span>
```

In the example above, you could hypothetically use `.element > span:first-child > a:first-child`, but that becomes extremely rigid and heavily depends on the nesting structure, which in my case changes depending on the place it appears in the document.  Normally I would adjust the HTML to have a more consistent and easier structure, but I don't have that freedom at this time, I just need to work with what's available.

Is there some kind of CSS magic I can use to select only the first match, regardless of depth?  Or will I just plain need additional classes?

Comment: This other question doesn't use the expression "first matched element", but it's similar in principle: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524415/matching-the-first-nth-element-of-a-certain-type-in-the-entire-document

Comment: Thanks guys!  So far it seems like my question hasn't -quite- been answered before, but Stack Overflow is a big place, lol.  Regardless, I think I found a pretty satisfying answer, and I hope it helps anyone else searching for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a single selector that will cover that.

So you have pretty much two choices, either add a class, or use this trick, where you CAN apply styling in a way that will visually appear to affect only the element(s) you care about.

The idea is simply to get it half-right with the first selector `.element a:first-of-type` and then override/restore the ones that were incorrectly matched with a second selector `.element :not(:first-child) a` - this will also match `<a>` tags that were not `first-of-type`, so it seems like a good place to put your default styling along with `.element a`, to cover the rest.

```css
.element {
  display: block;
}

/* first <a> tags to appear at any level turn blue */
.element a:first-of-type {
  color: blue;
}

/* "restore" styling on <a> tags with any parent that isn't the first child */
/* also, set default styling in one place */
.element :not(:first-child) a,
.element a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<span class="element">
  <span>
    <a>Demo</a> <!-- Select this one -->
    <a>Demo</a>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a>Demo</a>
    <a>Demo</a>
  </span>
</span>

<span class="element">
  <span>
    <span>
      <a>Demo</a> <!-- Select this one, further nested -->
      <a>Demo</a>
    </span>
  </span>
  <span>
    <a>Demo</a>
    <a>Demo</a>
  </span>
</span>
```

Comment: Maybe someday they'll add something like `:first-match` to the spec, but until then, this is perfect.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonDeWitt and BDawg -- Yepp, there was a 3rd way :) ... do note though, with this you can't use a global rule like `a { color: green }`, as the above reset trick will override it, no matter where you position that rule, having lower specificity.

Comment: Yeah, I kinda figured no answer would be perfect, due to css selector hell, lol.  But, until my freedom to modify the HTML becomes a little more open, I gotta make it work somehow.  That said, I like the idea of just using that rule as the default, instead of "reverting" it to the default.

Comment: After some thinking, I found yours better than mine, so I moved a part of mine to yours, gave it an upvote and delete mine.