# how to take one element of the same selector?

Tags: html, css, html-select

So I have some html code like this :

```html
`<body>

    <header>
        Hallo
    </header>

    <div class="A">
        <div class="B">
            <h1>First</h1>
            
            <div class="C">
                <img src="blabla.png">
                <div class="D">
                    <h2>1</h2>
                    <p>blabla</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="C">
                <img src="blabal.jpg">
                <div class="D">
                    <h2>2</h2>
                    <p>blabal</p>
                </div>
            </div>

        <div class="B">
            <h1>Second</h1>
            
            <div class="C">
                <img src="Blabla">
                <div class="D">
                    <h2>3</h2>
                    <p>blabla</p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="C">
                <img src="blablaa.png">
                <div class="D">
                    <h2>4</h2>
                    <p>blabla</p>
                </div>
            </div>      
            
        </div>
    </div>
</body>`
```

how I can get the element of `<h2>1</h2>` and color it? I cann find a way to take just one element, because all functions refers to "every" and "all". does anyonecan show me a way how to do it ?
thanks

Comment: What is your condition to color or to don't h2 ?

Comment: I can't change anything in HTML file, all I can do just in CSS file

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('h2')[0].style.color="red";
document.querySelector('h2').style.color="red";

Answer (score 2):

`:first-child` maybe

```css
.A > .B:first-child > h1:first-child  + .C h2 {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  Hallo
</header>

<div class="A">
  <div class="B">
    <h1>First</h1>

    <div class="C">
      <img src="blabla.png">
      <div class="D">
        <h2>1</h2>
        <p>blabla</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="C">
      <img src="blabal.jpg">
      <div class="D">
        <h2>2</h2>
        <p>blabal</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="B">
      <h1>Second</h1>

      <div class="C">
        <img src="Blabla">
        <div class="D">
          <h2>3</h2>
          <p>blabla</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="C">
        <img src="blablaa.png">
        <div class="D">
          <h2>4</h2>
          <p>blabla</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `querySelector()` method returns the first element that matches a specified CSS selector(s) in the document.

EDIT:

Than you can do like this:

```
<script>
    var l = document.querySelectorAll('h2');
    l[0].style.color="red";
    l[1].style.color="green";
</script>
```

EDIT 2:

We can divide CSS selectors into categories:

1. Simple selectors (select elements based on name, id, class)
2. Combinator selectors (select elements based on a specific
   relationship between them)
3. Pseudo-class selectors (select elements based on a certain state)
4. Pseudo-elements selectors (select and style a part of an element)
5. Attribute selectors (select elements based on an attribute or
   attribute value)

finally realized with only selectors makes it impossible to navigate through hierarchically unrelated HTML elements.

if possible to include script file than go with it.

*related [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751127/how-to-select-the-first-second-or-third-element-with-a-given-class-name)*

Comment: This would apply the color to *all* the `h2` tags, which is not what the OP wants.

Comment: @SidPro it doesn't work. `<h2>2</h2>`, `<h2>3</h2>` and` <h2>4</h2>` will get the same color. I did write that they have same **Selector**. your function will work if they are different

Comment: @SidPro that's not even in CSS file. I can't change Html file. thats the rule I got

Answer (score 0):

There are some answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524415/matching-the-first-nth-element-of-a-certain-type-in-the-entire-document) that rely on JS/JQuery.

However (to avoid JS) you can also just add a `class` attribute to the element like this:

```
<h2 class="element-to-color">1</h2>
```

and select it in CSS like this:

```
.element-to-color {
  color: blue;  /* or some other color */
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, I can't do that. I can't change anything in Html file

Comment: Well the HTML will have to change in *some* way. Could you clarify what the restrictions are? You'll either have to attach CSS or JS -- and both would modify the HTML..

Comment: the restrictions are I can't change the html file and I only got an empty CSS file. thats it. and the task is to color `<h2>1</h2>`.