# css selector for nth element of type - weird implementation of nth-of-type()

Tags: javascript, html, dom, css-selectors

I may be stupid but I'm trying to select the 2nd div that has the class specialclass. Whats the right querySelector for this?

For test purpost I thought to use `document.querySelector("#content-wrapper > .specialclass:nth-of-type(2)");` I thought `nth-of-type` is used for this. but it returns undefined.`nth-of-type` as well as `nth-child` seem to count from the parent element. The problem is that the order of elements change pretty often.

Website Structure

```
 <div id="content-wrapper">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="specialclass">Can be selectet through document.querySelector(".specialclass:nth-of-type(3)");</div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="specialclass">element I'd like to select. Can be selectet through document.querySelector(".specialclass:nth-of-type(7)");</div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="a"></div>
</div>
```

IMPORTANT: Please be aware I CANNOT change the website markup!

Comment: Try `#content-wrapper>.specialclass~.specialclass`?

Comment: Looks like another duplicate of: [how can i select first second or third element with given class name using CSS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751127/how-can-i-select-first-second-or-third-element-with-given-class-name-using-css). However, considering the markup, the above ^ solution works.

Comment: Also could be a dublicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921809/css3-nth-of-type-restricted-to-class

Comment: While very closely related, I can't see closing this javascript question as a duplicate of a css question.  @BoltClock's answer for example would not be valid in either of those css questions but certainly is here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "type" in `:nth-of-type()` refers to the element type, which in this case is `div`. Since the children are all `div` elements, `:nth-of-type()` functions identically to `:nth-child()`. This is entirely by design.

While the general problem of [trying to select the nth child matching a specific selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5545649/css3-nth-childodd-with-a-selector) is commonly associated with a misconception of how `:nth-of-type()` works, this question isn't quite a duplicate of all the rest because they are all CSS-based, which poses certain limitations that are not present in selector APIs, such as the one provided by the DOM.

In your specific case, instead of trying to retrieve an individual element using `querySelector()`, you can use `querySelectorAll()` to select all the `.specialclass` elements and index off of the resulting node list to get the one you want (remember that this is a zero-based index, unlike the structural pseudo-classes which are one-based):

```
var secondElement = document.querySelectorAll("#content-wrapper > .specialclass")[1];
```

You *could* also use something like

```
var secondElement = document.querySelector("#content-wrapper > .specialclass ~ .specialclass");
```

as mentioned in the comments, and `querySelector()` (note: not `querySelectorAll()`) will only pick up the first such element — this is always the closest `.specialclass` that is a following sibling of the first `.specialclass` regardless of how many of these elements there are. However I prefer indexing off a node list as the intent is much clearer.